# Incorrect currency format in product and checkout pages

Tags: price, magento2.3, format

The store locale is bg_BG. After the product page is opened the price is rendered correctly formatted from the server.
When the following JS is executed the format is wrong.

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'priceBox'
    ], function($){
        var dataPriceBoxSelector = '[data-role=priceBox]',
            dataProductIdSelector = '[data-product-id=1]',
            priceBoxes = $(dataPriceBoxSelector + dataProductIdSelector);

        priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
            return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
        });

        priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': {"productId":"1","priceFormat":{"pattern":"%s\u00a0\u043b\u0432.","precision":2,"requiredPrecision":2,"decimalSymbol":",","groupSymbol":"\u00a0","groupLength":2,"integerRequired":false}}});
    });
</script>
```

I cannot find what is causing this issue and how to fix it. Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Examples:
Before JS:
1 199,00 лв.
155,00 лв.
after the JS:
11 99,00 лв.
1 55,00 лв.

Comment: I updated my answer, check if works for you now

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem @kolek?

Answer (score 2):

You can make check for currency in the Plugin.

Create `etc/frontend/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface">
        <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Framework\Locale\Format" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create `{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Framework\Locale\Format` class:

```
namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Framework\Locale;

/**
 * Class Format
 * @package {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Framework\Locale
 */
class Format
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface
     */
    private $scopeResolver;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface $scopeResolver)
    {
        $this->scopeResolver = $scopeResolver;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetPriceFormat(
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $currency = $this->scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();

        if ($currency->getCode() == 'BGN') {
            $result['groupLength'] = 3;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the prices grouped by 3  (1 199,00 лв) you need to set the `groupLength` property from `priceBox` to `3` :

**UPDATE**

Improving my answer, you can create an after plugin for `\Magento\Framework\Locale\Format` and set there the `groupLength` to `3`:

Create `etc/frontend/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format">
        <plugin name="formatConfig"
                type="< Vendor>\< ModuleName>\Plugin\Locale\Format"
                sortOrder="100"
        />
    </type>

</config>
```

Create `< Vendor>\< ModuleName>\Plugin\Locale\Format` :

```
<?php

namespace < Vendor>\< ModuleName>\Plugin\Locale;

class Format
{
    public function afterGetPriceFormat(\Magento\Framework\Locale\Format $subject, $result)
    {
        $result["groupLength"] =3;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure, but the format options are dynamically generated in PHP based on the current locale, so this is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I found but was not able to resolve correctly is that the format of the price is not returned correctly by NumberFormatter->getPattern on line 102 magento/framework/Locale/Format.php. The only reason I see for this is the ICU Version of the Intl extension. For now, I was able to test it with ICU 60.2, 60.3. I'm having the issue with both of the versions and I know it is ok with 50, 55, 57

Hope it may help someone else with the same issue and if you find a solution please reply to that thread.

Answer (score 0):

There аре only 2 options to solve the problem:

1. Not good one:  Compile php-intl with ICU 57.1 maximum. All versions after this one have broken currency pattern for bg_BG locale. The correct patterns should be "#,##0.00 ¤". [Here are instructions how to do this](https://realpandablog.wordpress.com/2018/02/09/how-to-upgrade-icu-in-intl-in-php-7-0-x-for-linux-ubuntu-16-04/)
2. Good one: Create custom class overriding magento Format class. [Here are some instructions how to do this](https://webkul.com/blog/change-format-price-magento-2/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Magento 2.3.3. I couldn't find a way to solve the problem programmatically but I found a work-around. You can install MagePlaza's Currency Formatter extension:
https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-currency-formatter

Then simply configure the currency format as you wish. I attach a photo of a sample Bulgarian format.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello im beginer any can make this file and send to me cuz not understand how to make.
Im make folder Vendor\currency\Plugin\Locale\ and in directory Locale in put script and file name is Format.php
But show this error Plugin class Vendor\currency\Plugin\Framework\Locale\Format doesn't exist or {Vendor}{ModuleName} what name need to be and script what name.php need be.
Mageplazza extention not fix this problem.